# Pragmatische Verwendung von "Sie"

Tags: style

Mir ist in letzter Zeit aufgefallen, dass drei Benutzer mit denen ich Kontroversen hatte, mich plötzlich mit "Sie" anschreiben. Meine Frage ist eher genereller Natur: Inwieweit glaubt ihr, dass die Verwendung von "Sie" in spezifischen Kontexten dazu dient, Aversion zu signalisieren?

Aufgrund einiger Kommentare hier möchte ich ganz klar betonen, dass es mir nicht um diese Benutzer geht, die ich nicht einmal namentlich erwähnt habe. Sie waren nur der Anlass meiner Frage, die auf rein pragmatischem Interesse beruht.

Comment: Ich verwende `du` in einem lockeren Umfeld. Gerade im Internet geht man beim siezen zum gegenüber auf Distanz, das muss aber nichts mit Aversion zu tun haben.  So, wie sie mich in quasi jedem Kommentar angehen, sehe zumindest ich keinen Grund dazu, mit ihnen in einem lockeren Verhältnis zu schreiben.

Comment: Der Kern der Frage ist wahrscheinlich eine berechtigte Frage. Wie sie gestellt wurde führt potentiell allerdings zu Unfrieden. Da wäre eine neutrale Fragestellung besser gewesen. Evtl eignet sie sich auch besser fürs meta oder für interpersonal SE.

Comment: Das erklärt nur den Anlass meiner Fragestellung. Wenn ich das wegließe, würde die Frage wenig Sinn machen. Nochmal: Es ist nicht meine Intention, Unfrieden zu stiften. Ich finde, man kann diese Frage durchaus objektiv beantworten, wenn man Interesse hat. Wenn nicht, ist es auch OK für mich.

Comment: @Nico _"Es ist nicht meine Intention, Unfrieden zu stiften."_ Das tut es aber offensichtlich. Lass' den _Anlass_ vielleicht besser weg.

Comment: @Nico Deine Editierung der Frage ist nicht wirklich hilfreich. Bitte versuche ein komplett neutrales Beispiel zu finden, und lasse den _"Anlass"_ komplett weg.

Comment: Gut, dann denke ich mir aus, dass gestern jemand mich auf der Straße beleidigt hat. Geht das?

Comment: Schreib doch einfach sinngemäß: In deutschen Online-Foren ist es Usus, dass sich die Nutzer Duzen. Welche Grund kann es geben, dass eine Person eine andere in dieser oder anderen Situationen plötzlich Siezt? Werden damit Aversionen signalisiert? - Ist zwar dann etvl mehr interpersonal se als german se, aber da findests schon noch den Dreh.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass es darauf eine generell gütige /"richtige" Antwort gibt: manche Menschen benutzen das *Sie*, im Aversionen zu signalisieren, andere nicht. In einer bestimmten Situation mag es so gemeint sein, in einer anderen nicht. Daher habe ich dafür gestimmt, die Frage als opinion-based zu schließen.

Comment: Nein, ich lasse mich nicht durch irgendwelche Simulierungssuggestionen verbiegen. Habe ganz klar geschrieben, worum es im Kern geht. Wenn ihr denkt, die Frage stellt einen Verstoß dar, schlagt ruhig ein "close" vor. Hab da nix gegen.

Comment: @Arsak Dein gutes Recht! PS. Ist jede Frage, für die es keine schwarz/weiß Antwort gibt "opinion based"?

Comment: @Nico _"dass gestern jemand mich auf der Straße beleidigt hat"_ Indem er Dich gesietzt hat?? :D

Comment: Du hast doch unten ein Beispiel angebracht (das du dann gelöscht hast), in dem Beleidigungen mit "Sie" verbunden waren.

Comment: @nico Hier ist es nochmal zum Nachlesen: [Sie Arschloch!](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=4&idThread=337650&lp=ende&lang=en). Wie gesagt war mein Kommentar eher sarkastischer Natur. Und ich bin nach wie vor der Meinung, dass diese Frage zu nichts Gutem führt, und besser gelöscht werden sollte.

Comment: Ich habe fairerweise ein "close" vorgeschlagen, wenn viele der Meinung sind. Ansonsten freue ich mich über weitere Antworten wie die von @volker

Comment: Ich finde die Diskussion auf dem zitierten Leo Artikel ausgesprochen amüsant (siehe z.B. das Unterthema _"Halbdackel"_).

Comment: Dasselbe Problem besteht in allen Sprachen mit 2 oder mehr Höflichkeitsformen. Dazu kann man sogar Englisch zählen, denn hier wird zwischen der Anrede per Vornamen und der Anrede per Titel oder Nachnamen unterschieden. Das in der Frage gestellte Problem ist also kein Problem der deutschen Sprache, also hier off topic.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Den Anlass zu verbergen halte ich für noch problematischer, weil die 3 User den Fall vielleicht auch ohne expliziten Hinweis wiedererkennen. Dann hätten wir womöglich eine verdeckte Insiderdiskussion innerhalb der allgemeinen. Daher pflichte ich Nico bei, ist es besser, den Anlass transparent zu machen, aber auf die generelle Natur abzustellen. Übrigens führt potenziell jede Frage zu Unfrieden - das kann kein Kriterium sein.

Answer (score 5):

Im normalen Alltag ist es üblich bzw. wird erwartet, dass man gegenüber Fremden, Geschäftspartnern, Kollegen<sup>*</sup> oder Respektspersonen *höflich* ist, was durch das Siezen ausgedrückt wird, während das *vertrauliche* "Du" - abgesehen von Kindern (auch fremden) - nur gegenüber Verwandten oder Freunden benutzt wird - oder gegenüber Fremden, mit denen man im Streit ist und/oder die man gezielt durch diese Respektlosigkeit beleidigen will.
Nun gibt es aber Gemeinschaften, in denen es üblich ist, dass alle einander duzen. Das kann das Fitness-Center sein, ein Start-Up-Unternehmen, die Teilnehmer eines Lehrgangs - oder eben das Internet. Dadurch soll eine "wir sind eine große Familie"-Mentalität ausgedrückt oder überhaupt erst erzeugt werden. Und in einem solchen Umfeld, in dem ein *vertrauter Umgangston **erwartet*** wird, kann man eben durch *demonstrative Höflichkeit* Distanz zum Ausdruck bringen.

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>Der Kollege kann zusätzlich auch ein Freund sein, der geduzt wird, ist es aber nicht automatisch.</sub>

Comment: Ich sehe es in den meisten Fällen, die du erwähnst, ähnlich. 1) "Das vertrauliche "Du" [...] Fremden [...] die man gezielt durch diese Respektlosigkeit beleidigen will". Ja, "Sie Scheusal" würde geradezu das Gegenteil bewirken, d.h. einen Lachanfall. 2). Das "Sie" unter Kollegen mag vom Berufsfeld abhängen. In meinem z.B. ist das "du" gang und gebe. Insgesamt beobachte ich eine Tendenz zur "Dedistanzierung" sozusagen. Vielleicht durch den angelsächsischen Einfluss bedingt, kommt es nicht selten vor, dass man im offiziellen Brief- oder Emailverkehr mit "Lieber Herr xy" adressiert wird.